# Parsing JSON response from Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

This might be a simple question, so sorry for that. I'm trying to develop a radio app for my internet radio station. I'm using JSON format for the requests ([Example JSON](http://cp.usa6.fastcast4u.com:2199/rpc/radiasiy/streaminfo.get)) to get information from my station. For example the "title" tag. I want to get this information.

My first try:

```
  JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
  songname.setText(data.getString("title"));
```

But the problem is that I cannot get this information. What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your response look like?

Comment: Add your JSON to the question

Comment: while your key "data" is jsonArray and you are converting in JSONObject so error gives

Comment: http://cp.usa6.fastcast4u.com:2199/rpc/radiasiy/streaminfo.get This is my JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your JSON do like this

```
JSONObject josnOBJ = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray jArray = josnOBJ.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject jsonData = null;
String title = null;

for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
  try {
        jsonData  = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        title= jsonData  .optString("title");
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // Oops
      }
}
songname.setText(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some generic JSON parsers instead of manual work. Eg: https://github.com/bajicdusko/AndroidJsonProvider

Just create model class regarding your json content. Check examples in README on github url.

Hope i could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON library in case you have lot of values to fetch from JSON ,that would take care of everything for you.